# Materialize en Cordova no funciona

Tags: css, bootstrap, cordova, materialize, apache-cordova

Hola he estado probando Rachet, bootstrap y materialize pero ninguno hace por funcionar he estado mirando como lo tenia en otros proyectos de paginas web que funcionaban y aun poniendolo exactamente igual tampoco funciona y no se por que, he probado a descargarlo con npm, de forma manual e incluso usando el cdn pero no parece que nada funcione aqui os dejo el codigo por si alguno me puede ayudar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Borja</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m8 l4 offset-m2 offset-l4">
                  <div class="card">
              
                    <div class="card-action teal lighten-1 white-text">
                      <h3>Login Form</h3>
                    </div>
              
                    <div class="card-content">
                      <div class="form-field">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username">
                      </div><br>
              
                      <div class="form-field">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password">
                      </div><br>
              
                      <div class="form-field">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remem">
                        <label for="remem">Rememeber me</label>
                        
                      </div><br>
              
                      <div class="form-field">
                        <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-dark" style="width:100%;">Login</button>
                      </div><br>
                    </div>
              
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando acá es que en la meta data de `Content-Security-Policy` no le estas asignando los scripts y estilos que vas a usar. lo que hice fue modificar tu código e ingrese códigos para que autorice el uso de `script` `JS` y también del `css`.

Si no entendiste muy bien lo que quise poner te dejo este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

**tu meta data:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

**te tiene que quedar así:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: ay dios muchisimas gracias estaba ya cansado de buscar y no encontrar nada ^^